# Do I need Turkey Visa

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, turkish-airlines, e-visas

I have an Indian passport and am planning to visit Chicago USA with a valid visa. To book a flight for Chicago (Mumbai – Chicago ), I came across some connected flights Turkish Airlines that stop at Istanbul layover 19 hrs.

Do I need to have visa for Turkey or Require any hotel booking ? any information on this will be helpful.